# How to make this function return False for number = 1

Tags: python

Edit: Fixed

```
def is_perfect_number(number):
    sum_of_the_divisors = 0
    for divisors in range(1, number):
        if number % divisors == 0:
            sum_of_the_divisors += divisors
            if sum_of_the_divisors == number:
                continue
            if sum_of_the_divisors > number:
                return False
        else:
            if divisors == number:
                return False
            else:
                continue
    if sum_of_the_divisors == number:
        return True


number = 1
print(f'{number}: {is_perfect_number(number)}')

for i in range(1, 10000):
     if is_perfect_number(i):
         print(f'{i}: {is_perfect_number(i)}')
```

Output:

So I want to make this function  work without having to:

```
if number == 1:
    return False
```

I want it to work like a normal proper function without excluding 1 e.g.:

```
if number == divisor:
    return False
```

I tried many methods in making it work, it works with any number and since perfect number > 0, the only number that returns None or wrong information is 1. The perfect number is a number like:
6 all of its divisors add up to 6, 6 = 1 + 2 + 3. However, divisor must be lesser than the number given. So 1 has no divisors that match this definiton.

```
def is_perfect_number(number):
    sum_of_the_divisors = 0
    for divisor in range(1, number):
        if number == divisor:
            return False
        if number % divisor == 0:
            sum_of_the_divisors += divisor
            if sum_of_the_divisors == number:
                continue
            if sum_of_the_divisors > number:
                return False
        else:
            if divisor == number:
                return False
            else:
                continue
    return sum_of_the_divisors == number


number = 1
print(f'{number}: {is_perfect_number(number)}')

for i in range(1, 10000):
     if is_perfect_number(i):
         print(f'{i}: {is_perfect_number(i)}')
```

So why does this work that way? @awesoon

Comment: The upper bound of a "range" is exclusive, i. e. "range(1, 1)" contains nothing.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `for divisor in range(1, number):`, exactly which values do you expect `divisor` to have, each time through the loop?

Comment: "the only number that returns None or wrong information is 1." Look closely at the end of the function. `if sum_of_the_divisors == number: return True` Okay, and what if that *isn't* the case?

Comment: Your function returns `None` for `1`. Just replace last `if` with `return sum_of_the_divisors == number`

Comment: Try to write out your intended logic with an actual pencil and piece of paper, and draw a flowchart. Think carefully about whether you are *actually done with the calculation* at various points in that process. After `sum_of_the_divisors += divisor`, for example, should the function continue to look for more valid `divisor` values? Why or why not? Under what conditions?

Comment: So basically I should just change in range(1, number) to in range(0, number)?

Comment: if number % divisors == 0:
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

Comment: and for in range(1, number + 1) It just returns False to everything

Comment: @awesoon why does it work?

Answer (score 1):

this is my first attempt at answering a question on here.

```
import numpy as np

def is_number_perfect(number):
    if number <= 0:
        result = False
    else:
        divisors = np.arange(1, number)
        sum_of_divisors = 0

        for divisor in divisors:
            if number % divisor == 0:
                sum_of_divisors += divisor
                if sum_of_divisors > number:
                    result = False

        if sum_of_divisors == number:
            result = True

        else:
            result = False
    return result
```

Any tips for how I can improve are welcome. Thank you!

Comment: That's fine but what I wanted was something that does not exclude 0 and  1 from the possibilities . This is what do not want.
    if number <= 0:
        result = False

Comment: Adding additional explanation as to why your solution works always appreciated on stackoverflow. Thanks for posting, welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: @lane Thanks for the heads up, really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_perfect_number(number):
    sum_of_the_divisors = 0
    for divisor in range(1, number):
        if number % divisor == 0:
            sum_of_the_divisors += divisor
            if sum_of_the_divisors == number:
                return True
            else:
                continue
    return sum_of_the_divisors == number

   
number = 1
print(f'{number}: {is_perfect_number(number)}')

for i in range(1, 10000):
     if is_perfect_number(i):
         print(f'{i}: {is_perfect_number(i)}')
```

1: False

6: True

24: True

28: True

496: True

2016: True

8128: True

8190: True

Comment: or just do `return sum_of_the_divisors == number`

Comment: that's what @awersoon suggested but why does it work and not the if? That's what I'm unable to comprehend. Edit: I got it.

Comment: Yes @SembeiNorimaki is correct, `return sum_of_the_divisors == number` is the way to go. I was trying to change as little of the code as possible, but in retrospect, that was silly of me. :)

Comment: @Jirafey just to clarify, the reason it won't work is because looping a range of (1,1) is not looping - you're starting at 1 and ending at 1 - in other words, you're not looping. Another thing you could do is to put an `else` at the end of your `for` loop and return False, but that is also a special case - so I didn't suggest it.